# acm.program.GraphicsProgram, not able to get appropriate size of canvas

Tags: java

This is not a homework problem. I am only going over a freely available course from Stanford. I am using Ubuntu Linux with Eclipse.

Problem and Question:
I am drawing rectangles by calling add() on a acm.program.GraphicsProgram object. I am drawing certain number of rectangles which have a certain fixed width. However I am seeing that my rectangles are flowing off the visible area. I have tried setting a big enough width and height for both the GraphicsProgram object and the GCanvas object but still my rectangles are falling off the visible area. I always get the same height for GraphicsProgram object no matter what height I set.  Any pointers as to what am I doing wrong?

```
    import acm.graphics.*;
    import acm.program.*;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class Pyramid extends GraphicsProgram {

    /** Width of each brick in pixels */
            private static final int BRICK_WIDTH = 30;

    /** Width of each brick in pixels */
            private static final int BRICK_HEIGHT = 12;

    /** Number of bricks in the base of the pyramid */
            private static final int BRICKS_IN_BASE = 14;

            public void run() {

                    setWindowSize();
                    this.createPyramid();
            }

            private void createPyramid()
            {
                    int centerX = findCenter();
                    int startingX = centerX - (BRICKS_IN_BASE / 2) * BRICK_WIDTH;
                    int startingY = BRICK_HEIGHT;

                    for(int numBricks = BRICKS_IN_BASE; numBricks>= 1; numBricks--)
                    {
                            this.layBricks(startingX,startingY , numBricks);
                            startingX = startingX + BRICK_WIDTH / 2;
                            startingY = (BRICKS_IN_BASE - numBricks + 2) * BRICK_HEIGHT;
                    }
            }

            private void layBricks(int x, int y, int numOfBricks)
            {
                    for(int i = 0; i < numOfBricks; i++)
                    {
                            add(new GRect(x,y,this.BRICK_WIDTH, this.BRICK_HEIGHT));
                            x+=this.BRICK_WIDTH;
                    }

            }
            private void setWindowSize()
            {
                    int width = BRICK_WIDTH * BRICKS_IN_BASE * 2;
                    int height = BRICKS_IN_BASE * BRICK_HEIGHT * 2;

                    this.setSize(width, height);
                    //this.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                    //this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                    //this.getGCanvas().setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
                    //this.getGCanvas().add(new GRect(0,0,300,30));
                    //this.getGCanvas().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    System.out.println(this.getHeight());
                    System.out.println(this.getWidth());
                    System.out.println(this.getGCanvas().getHeight());
                    System.out.println(this.getGCanvas().getWidth());
            }


            private int findCenter()
            {

                    return this.getWidth() / 2;

            }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was that I was using open-java-jdk and not sun-java-jdk. After changing the jre my Applet is behaving in a more predictable way.

Answer (score 4):

I'm working through the same Stanford course online and ran into the same problem. The setSize method would resize the display but not the values returned by getWidth and getHeight.

You can change the width and height by going to Project > Properties > Run/Debug Settings > Edit > Parameters tab.

I assume there is something more direct or code-based, but this is an easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

Start by not hard coding the brick sizes like this

```
        int brick_width = (getWidth() / BRICKS_IN_BASE) - (getWidth() / 50);
        int brick_height = (brick_width / 3);
```

That way your pyramid will always be drawn within whatever the screen size happens to be.
It should also be centered, once your brick sizes are relative to window size, guaranteeing that the bricks will always be centered becomes easier. The only wrench I have found are weird
window sizes such as 50 x 500, but that doesn't happen too often.

Here is a look at my solution

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Pyramid1 extends GraphicsProgram {



 public void run(){

    int brick_width = (getWidth() / BRICKS_IN_BASE) - (getWidth() / 50);
    int brick_height = (brick_width / 3);
    for(int n = 0; n < BRICKS_IN_BASE; n++ ){
        //make a row at level n of bricks that is BRICKS_IN_BASE - n bricks wide.
        int bricks_in_level = BRICKS_IN_BASE - n;
        int x = ((getWidth() / 2) - ((bricks_in_level * brick_width) / 2)); //find the center then offset to farthest left.
        int y = (((getHeight() / 2) + ((BRICKS_IN_BASE / 2) * brick_height )) - ((n + 1) * brick_height)); //start at the 1/2 and move down half max stack height and move up a brick each round.
        GRect brick = new GRect(x, y, brick_width, brick_height);
        brick.setFilled(true);
        brick.setFillColor(Color.RED);
        add(brick);

        if(bricks_in_level > 1){ //If there are 2 or more bricks needed in this level
            for(int needed_bricks = bricks_in_level - 1; needed_bricks > 0; needed_bricks -= 1){
                x += brick_width;
                GRect needed_brick = new GRect(x, y, brick_width, brick_height);
                needed_brick.setFilled(true);
                needed_brick.setFillColor(Color.RED);
                add(needed_brick);
            }
        }
    }

 }
private static final int BRICKS_IN_BASE = 12;
}
```